# UIActivityViewController excludedActivityTypes not work

Tags: ios, swift, uiactivityviewcontroller

I want to exclude Weibo and WeChat, and set the following code:

```
let av = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: items, applicationActivities:nil)
av.excludedActivityTypes = [.postToWeibo, .postToTencentWeibo]
self.present(av, animated: true)
```

No matter what I did, the two apps still show up on UIActivityViewController. But excluding mail and copyToPasteboard are both work

```
av.excludedActivityTypes = [.postToWeibo, .postToTencentWeibo, .copyToPasteboard, .mail]
```

Any other way to exclude them? Thanks